# NotYetImplemented at Document.exports.nyil, at CookieService.get [as cookieString] in my project ..../dist/server.js file

Tags: angular, angular-universal

After running this "npm run serve:ssr" I am getting this error...

Node server listening on http://localhost:4201
ERROR Error: NotYetImplemented
at Document.exports.nyi (/Documents/projects/angular/dist/server.js:27677:9)
    at CookieService.get [as cookieString] (/Documents/projects/angular/dist/server.js:202759:29)
    at CookieService._cookieReader (/Documents/projects/angular/dist/server.js:203000:57)
    at CookieService.get (/Documents/projects/angular/dist/server.js:202799:40)